# Protecting class invariants

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on refactoring the GUI layer of our code base, and have run in to some trouble with enforcing the class invariant in the following design:

```
public interface IScreen {
  void Open();
  void Close();
  bool IsOpen { get; }
  ...
}

// class invariant: only the screen at the top of the stack should be open
public interface IScreenStack {
  void Push(IScreen screen);
  IScreen Pop();
  IScreen Peek();
}
```

A naive(?) implementation of `IScreenStack` may call `IScreen.Open()` and `IScreen.Close()` in an attempt to enforce its invariant. However, this does not guard against other parties calling those functions as well (and thereby breaking the invariant).

Some possible solutions I have explored with limited succes:

1. Use the `internal` keyword to hide `Open()`/`Close()` in an `IScreen` implementation, then make `IScreenStack` depend on that implementation. This seems like a bad idea resulting in an incomplete interface (`IScreen` still contains `IsOpen`, but not `Open()`/`Close()`).
2. Make a specific implementation of `IScreen` manage the stack directly by injecting `Stack<IScreen>` in its constructor. This would not prevent third parties from tampering with the stack.
3. Introduce some kind of third party (`IScreenController`?) to coordinate between `IScreen` and `IScreenStack`. This still doesn't exclude other third parties from breaking the invariant.

Any ideas/pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: and how was it solved, if was?

Answer (score -1):

In `C#` the best fit in case when you need a base `interface`, but also would provide some custom logic shared among all children of it, is using `abstract` class.

With abstract class you can define absrtact methods that *have to be overriden*, and non abstract ones, that can handle correctly internal logic.

```
public abstract class AbsScreenStack {

    //child HAS to override this for it's own implementation
    public abstract void DoSomething(); 

    public AbsScreenStack Pop() {

       .......
       //HANDLE STACK AND APPLIED TO IT RULES HERE. 
       //THIS IS SHARED FOR ALL CHILDREN OF THIS CLASS
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would prevent other classes from calling Open() or Close() on IScreen, and thereby invalidating AbsScreenStack's class invariant (only the top IScreen on its stack may be open).

For example:
`absScreenStack.Push(someScreen);
absScreenStack.Push(someOtherScreen);
someScreen.Open(); // now two screens on the stack are open, instead of one`

Comment: The point is that you have more control. So you can validate what to do when one eventually calls Open/Close.